# Bitbucket does not show all branches

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, git-branch, remote-branch

I have a repository on bitbucket that contains three branches. I'm able to list the remote branches using a good old `git branch --remote` command, and everything works perfectly. However, when I visit my repository using a browser, I can only see two branches. Someone please help. Bitbucket just ate my branch

Comment: Mine got solved. I think it takes couple of minutes to actually sync the data from your local repository to git.
Just keep on refreshing it and your problem gets solved.

Comment: Check if you only commit the code, not push. If branch is new and no previous commit on it

Answer (score 12):

The "active" filter on the Bitbucket branch screen only shows the main branch (usually named "master") and any branches that are ahead of the main branch. You can click "merged" at the top of the list to see branches that are still open, but which are no longer ahead of main.

Bitbucket also won't show branches that have been deleted in the Bitbucket UI, or branches closed with the "close branch" checkbox when merging a pull request. You'd have to re-push those if you really want them.

Comment: I found it there. This was helpful. Thank you!