# Branch mismatch in Bitbucket Web UI and git cmd

Tags: git, bitbucket

We have a Bitbucket repo and I normally use the git cmd for displaying, creating and deleting (remote) branches. When I use `git branch -a`, I've got these results:

```
dev
master
feature/my-feature
hotfix/my-hotfix
v0.1
v1.1
remotes/origin/dev
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/feature/my-feature
remotes/origin/hotfix/my-hotfix
remotes/origin/v0.1
remotes/origin/v1.1
```

However, in Bitbucket Web UI, the dropdown only shows:

[image: Bitbucket Web UI dropdown]

```
dev
master
feature/my-feature
v0.1
```

So why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following answer, Bitbucket only shows active branches (i.e. haven't already been merged with master).

[Bitbucket does not show all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45987963/bitbucket-does-not-show-all-branches)

In your scenario, I assume remotes/origin/feature/my-feature and remotes/origin/hotfix/my-hotfix and remotes/origin/v1.1 have been merged already.